# Update the NULL Rows with Previous NOT NULL Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario where my table has 2 columns and one column has series of dates and another one has some values. Now i need to update the null values with the value corresponding to the most recent date like below.

[image]

I can't use LEAD and LAG functions as I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

Sample data is in the below.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    Date_D DATE,
    Val INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table
(
    Date_D,
    Val
)
VALUES
('2019-06-15', 2),
('2019-06-16', NULL),
('2019-06-17', NULL),
('2019-06-18', 7),
('2019-06-19', 1),
('2019-06-20', 5),
('2019-06-21', NULL),
('2019-06-22', NULL),
('2019-06-23', NULL),
('2019-06-24', NULL),
('2019-06-25', 9),
('2019-06-26', 5),
('2019-06-27', 3),
('2019-06-28', 4),
('2019-06-29', NULL),
('2019-06-30', 1)



SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest looking at Gaps and Islands if you haven't. Also, 2008(R2) has less than 4 weeks of support left, so you will want to look at getting that upgrade path finalised and deployed as soon as you can. Also, upgrading would solve your problem of not being able to use `LEAD` and `LAG` (not that you actually need them here).

Comment: [Gaps and Islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do as

```
SELECT Date_D, CASE WHEN Val IS NULL THEN
          (
            SELECT TOP 1 Val 
            FROM @Table 
            WHERE Val IS NOT NULL AND Date_D < T.Date_D 
            ORDER BY Date_D DESC
          ) ELSE Val END
FROM @Table T;
```

If you want to update the table then join it with the results.

For the `UPDATE`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Date_D, CASE WHEN Val IS NULL THEN
            (
              SELECT TOP 1 Val 
              FROM @Table 
              WHERE Val IS NOT NULL AND Date_D < T.Date_D 
              ORDER BY Date_D DESC
            ) ELSE Val END Val
  FROM @Table T
)
UPDATE T
SET T.Val = CTE.Val
FROM @Table T INNER JOIN CTE
ON T.Date_D = CTE.Date_D
WHERE T.Val IS NULL; --You can also AND Date_D BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

See how it's working on a [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16de0cf3ec16f9d71a7a1eec65b9fd63)

Comment: What if the update needs to be done only if the data exists for last 4 months, else we should leave it as NULL

Comment: If you feels that the answer is wrong or something, please feel free to leave a comment Mr. Downvoter.

Answer (score 3):

Update using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE T0
SET Val = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Val
    FROM @Table As T1
    WHERE Val IS NOT NULL
    AND T0.Date_D > T1.Date_D
    ORDER BY Date_D DESC
    ) 
FROM @Table As T0
WHERE Val IS NULL
```

Validate:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table
```

Results:

```
Date_D          Val
15.06.2019      2
16.06.2019      2
17.06.2019      2
18.06.2019      7
19.06.2019      1
20.06.2019      5
21.06.2019      5
22.06.2019      5
23.06.2019      5
24.06.2019      5
25.06.2019      9
26.06.2019      5
27.06.2019      3
28.06.2019      4
29.06.2019      4
30.06.2019      1
```

Comment: What if the update needs to be done only if the data exists for last 4 months, else we should leave it as NULL

Comment: You add a condition to the subquery where clause - `and T1.Date_D >= dateadd(month, -4. getdate)`

Comment: If this answers the question please mark it as the solution @Ram . You let other users know the answer was useful and you get reputation for taking to time to show your appreciation. You've never marked an answer you've received as the solution, so now is a good time to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is with a sub-select, selecting the TOP 1 non-NULL value before the current `Date_D`.